# POSIX command for `which --all`, to list all on PATH not just first?

Tags: path, command, which

Many shells have an `--all` flag to `which`:

> --all, -a        Print all matches in PATH, not just the first

But `which` is not POSIX-compliant; `shellcheck` points us at `command -v`.

`command` however has no similar flag to `--all`.

Answer (score 0):

`type -a -p` provides this functionality.

`-a` instructs it to provide all, not just the first.

`-p` says print path only (otherwise you get `<executable> is` prefixed to the path) and ignore non-file results, e.g. aliases. (Alternatively `-P` follows aliases and forces a PATH search.)

Comment: Your question is seeking something that is standards-conformant, however.

Comment: @JdeBP Is this not? (I admit my metric was 'does shellcheck tell me off', which with `type -a -p`, it doesn't.)